# mysql query become very slow when binlog rotate

Tags: mysql, mysqlbinlog

Mysql version is 5.7.13.
Everytime when binlog file rotate,all queries and dml become extremely   slow.
The server "freezes" for about 40 seconds.
In the slow query log, I just see commits and system/session variable queries (like select @@session.tx_read_only; ) that take about 20 secs.

==============master server my.cnf============ 
    [mysqld]

```
# Remove leading # and set to the amount of RAM for the most important data 
# cache in MySQL. Start at 70% of total RAM for dedicated server, else 10%. 
# innodb_buffer_pool_size = 128M 
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2048M 
innodb_log_file_size = 360M 
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M 
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2 
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct = 50 


# Remove leading # to turn on a very important data integrity option: logging 
# changes to the binary log between backups. 
# log_bin 

log-bin=/alidata1/binlog/mysql-bin 
expire_logs_days=7 
binlog-do-db=mydb 
sync_binlog=6 
server_id=10 

slow_query_log=on 
slow_query_log_file=/data/slow_query/slow_query.log 
log_queries_not_using_indexes=off 
long_query_time=1 
wait_timeout=10800 
max_connections=800 

sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES 
#character_set_server=utf8 
character-set-client-handshake=FALSE 
character-set-server=utf8mb4 
collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci 
init_connect='SET NAMES utf8mb4' 

[client] 
default-character-set=utf8mb4 

[mysql] 
default-character-set=utf8mb4
```

==============binlog files=============

[binlog files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNLua.png)

```
[root@iZ94aem4qr5Z binlog]# ll 
total 15873308 
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 629162145 Jul 10 16:15 mysql-bin.000253 
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 629160790 Jul 10 21:11 mysql-bin.000254 
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 629148120 Jul 11 08:35 mysql-bin.000255 
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 629167412 Jul 11 13:12 mysql-bin.000256 
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 143362983 Jul 11 14:25 mysql-bin.000257 
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 782 Jul 11 13:12 mysql-bin.index
```

==============mysql slow log==============

```
# User@Host: user[user] @ [10.24.165.8] Id: 130132 
# Query_time: 14.186255 Lock_time: 0.000000 Rows_sent: 1 Rows_examined: 0 
SET timestamp=1499749959; 
select @@session.tx_read_only; 

# User@Host: user[user] @ [10.25.208.208] Id: 130317 
# Query_time: 13.943930 Lock_time: 0.000000 Rows_sent: 1 Rows_examined: 0 
SET timestamp=1499749959; 
select @@session.tx_read_only; 

# User@Host: user[user] @ [10.24.165.8] Id: 130204 
# Query_time: 13.848498 Lock_time: 0.000000 Rows_sent: 1 Rows_examined: 0 
SET timestamp=1499749959; 
select @@session.tx_read_only; 

# User@Host: user[user] @ [10.24.165.8] Id: 130197 
# Query_time: 12.988434 Lock_time: 0.000000 Rows_sent: 1 Rows_examined: 0 
SET timestamp=1499749959; 
select @@session.tx_read_only;
```